# Qtip doesnt load REL URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, qtip, rel

I am using Jquery 1.4.4 with Qtip and i am trying to load an image for each individual list item, so i am using Content: URL:.attr(rel), but it wont load the url of the REL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.list-one li a[href]').each(function(){
  $(this).qtip({
     Content: { url: $(this).attr('rel') },
     position: {
     corner: {
        target: 'topMiddle',
        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                }
                },
     style: {
       tip: 'bottomMiddle',
       border: { width: 2, radius: 2, color: '#A9D041' },
     background: '#fff',
     padding:0,
     width: 175,
     height:100
       }  

   });
});
});
</script>




 <ul class="list-one">
 <li class="header">Project Management</li>
 <li><a href="#">BGC Bremerholm</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Medtronic</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Straumur - Burdaras Bank</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Straumur Reykjavik</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Straumur Stockholm</a></li>
 <li><a  rel="/test/test.html" href="#">T. Rowe Price</a></li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your test.html page to the same directory?  So your rel value would then be `test.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use each from jquery to get all elements and aply qtip to them. You can easily manipulate them in this way.

```
$('.qtip').each(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
      content: { url: $(this).attr('rel'), method: 'get' },

      style: {
         padding: '7px 13px',
         width: {
            max: 510,
            min: 0
         },
         tip: true
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Content](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content) should be a lowercase c

```
content: { url: $(this).attr('rel') },
```

Comment: GOT ITIt is highly recommended that all JavaScript includes like the one above be placed after all your content at the footer of the page, just before the end </body> tag. This ensures that all content is loaded before manipulation of the DOM occurs.

Answer (score 0):

goetz, the document.ready() function means you don't need to put it at the bottom of the page, it waits for the page to load before firing.

I used this for a recent project and it works just fine :)

```
$('.test').each(function(){
        $(this).qtip({
          content: { text: '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />' },
          show: { delay: 0 },
        });
      });
```